# Find all analytic functions $f(z)$ that satisfy $(f(z))^4=z^8$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an analytic function on $D\subseteq\mathbb{C}$, such that *D is open and connected* and $(f(z))^4=z^8$ for every $z\in D$. Prove that $f(z)$ is equal to one of the following functions:

$$f_1(z)=z^2 \text{ or } f_2(z)=-z^2 \text{ or } f_3(z)=iz^2\text{ or }f_4(z)=-iz^2$$

**My Solution**: (probably *wrong*) Let $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z^2}.$ Obviously $g(z)^4=\frac{f^4(z)}{z^8}=1$, therefore $g(z)$ is either $i,-1,-i$ or $1$. To find $f(z)$ one needs to multiply both sides of the four equations by $z^2$ and then $f(z)$ would be one of the given $f_i$.

**Problems with my solution**: First of all, if $0\in D$, then $g(z)$ is not defined well. That's the main problem. Second of all, I didn't use the fact that $f(z)$ is analytic; and that must be problematic. Besides, my solution seems way too short and "easy", so I'm pretty sure it's incorrect.

I would be happy to hear your thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: What are the conditions imposed on $D$ ? If for example $D$ is the union of two disjoint discs then the problem is (clearly) false.

Comment: @Lelouch There are no conditions on $D$. When you say the problem is false, do you mean that $f$ is not one of the given $f_i$, or that my proof is wrong?

Comment: Think of the case when $D$ has multiple components. $f$ may be a different $f_j$ on each component and still satisfy the power condition.

Comment: If $D$ is connected, then the statement is right and only requires continuity (which turns into analyticity a posteriori).

Comment: @AmitZach You can have $f$ reflect each one of your solutions if the domain is disjoint, kind of like you can do with locally constant functions.

Comment: I was not given any more conditions on $D$, but I edited the question and now $D$ is open and connected (I was not given that information, however I was told to assume that now)

Comment: @Thorgott why is the continuity required?

Comment: So that the function only assumes one of the forms throughout. Otherwise consider something like $z^2$ on the upper half-plane and $-z^2$ elsewhere; that satisfies the equation, but is not of the given form (and, also, discontinuous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is definitely on the right track, assuming that $D$ is connected.

Consider $g$ defined on $D\setminus\{0\}$.
You've already shown that for each $z$, $g(z) = 1,-1,i$ or $-i$.
But $g$ is analytic (continuity is enough) on $D\setminus\{0\}$, as the quotient between two analytic functions such that the denominator never vanishes.
It follows that $g$ must assume the same value throughout $D\setminus\{0\}$, which seals the deal.

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks! I said that $g(z)$ can be defined at $z=0$ as $1,-1,i$ or $-i$, and then it would be constant on the whole of $D$. Is that a correct way to solve the $z=0$ problem?

Comment: You don't really need to care about extending $g$ to $0$ (even though you can, by continuity). You know from the argument above that for some $j$ it's true that $f=f_j$ on $D\setminus\{0\}$. Because $f$ is analytic (again, continuity is enough), $f(0) = 0$. Or you can deduce that $f(0) = 0$ directly from $f(z)^4 = z^8$. Whatever the case, all $f_j$ are $0$ at $z=0$, so things work out okay without having to worry about $g(0)$.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

Just treat $z = 0$ separately: $(f(0))^4 = 0$ implies $f(0) = 0$, so that once again $f(z) = iz^2, z^2, -z^2$ or $-iz^2$... they just are all the same when $z = 0$.

You still have to show that for an analytic function on a connected domain that $f(z)$ cannot be more than one of these functions (except at $z = 0$ where they all agree).

Comment: Thank you very much!